# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object?"

Tags: vb.net

Trying to show other form if textbox's text is correct. When I debug I get an error saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". The code is below:

```
'OK is OK button, MainForm is the form I'm trying to open     

Private Sub OK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OK.Click
    Dim pass As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("password.txt")
    If PasswordTextBox.Text = pass Then
        MainForm.Owner = Me
        Me.Hide()
        '"Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error when debugging on line below
        MainForm.Show()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you declare and initialize `MainForm`? Btw, why do you have a password at all?

Comment: @Tim to protect from other people who use my computer a lot. don't wan't them using this program.

Comment: I don't think you can show a form whose owner is hidden, which is what you're trying to do. Does it work if you remove `Me.Hide()`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter the path for the text file is longer, I just cut it out because I don't want the world to know where everything is on my computer.

Comment: @StevenLiekens didn't work. I removed lines 6 and 7.

Comment: Oh dear God, a plain-text password file? Yikes.

Comment: You need to create a variable to hold the new instance of your main form. `Dim theFormIWantToShow As New MainForm       theFormIWantToShow.Show()`

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new instance of the form you want to display. You do this by creating a variable of form T and then showing it.

If you don't create an instance of your form the `MainForm.Show()` code will be invoking `Show()` on an null reference.

```
If PasswordTextBox.Text = pass Then
    Me.Hide()
    Dim theFormIWantToShow As New MainForm
    theFormIWantToShow.Show()
End If
```